# sockjs-node/info? 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, webpack

I've done lost of search for couple of hours now and still can't find what I'm looking for. Basically I get this error in the console when running ng serve in my **Angular 6 app**:

```
GET http://local.mywebsitesecure.com/sockjs-node/info?t=1540568455931 404 (Not Found)
```

Based on my research the solution could be just updating

> webpack.config.js

However, I can't find webpack.config.js  in my project. They also say to do:

> "ng eject"

to create a webpack, but it doesn't seem to work.

**SOLUTION:** I can get it to work by running this (It actually works!):

> ng serve --public-host=http://localhost:4200

BUT I want to be able to set this up somewhere in my app so that I can only do

> ng serve

Does anyone know how to fix this issue and gid rid of this error (**sockjs-node/info**). Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can edit your `angular.json` file and add the option for `public-host`. Mind you all options are camelCased not kebab-cased.

```
...
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "browserTarget": "congiftest:build",
    "publicHost":"http://localhost:4200"
  },
},
...
```

This will allow you to just run `ng serve` and the `public-host` flag will be added.

Comment: Have you tried this on .Net core - I've tried Https://localhost:5001/subfolder/ and it's still broken - I have tried many variations - any ideas?  I have tried both as a parameter and in angular.json.  I have my app being served inside a sub-folder.

Comment: @progx not at the moment, I was mostly answering your second question.

Comment: Is not there a typo? congiftest:build

Comment: Note to my future self and any googlers:
It seems like angular 11 has changed the behavior of the port when the application is proxied. Instead of the proxy-port, now the port specified on the command line (--port or the default) is used.
So anyone who develops through a reverse proxy now has to define the public host for any port different than 4200.